# Asp.Net Core - Prevent Session cookie conflict between same domain applications

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-core, cookies, session-cookies

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.2.

By default, session cookie is stored in a cookie named `.AspNetCore.Session` on a specific domain (e.g: `mydomain.com`).

In my case I have multiple .net core applications under the domain.  `mydomain.com/Module1`, `mydomain.com/Module2`, etc...

With this scenario, all the applications share the same cookie for their session. The consequence is that an application try to read the session of the other and generate a warning in the logs:

> Error unprotecting the session cookie. 
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {...} was not found in the key ring.

Although It's just a warning and session seems to working fine on each application, I wanted to know the proper way to handle this situation.

Thx.

Answer (score 15):

A solution that I've found is to change the session cookie name for each application:

In `Startup / Configure()` :

```
app.UseSession(new SessionOptions() { Cookie = new CookieBuilder() { 
    Name = ".AspNetCore.Session.MyApp1"}});
```

Comment: This answer has solved a similar issue that I was experiencing but I wanted more information on this. Can you elaborate why this was happening in the first place? Any articles or forums that I can refer to understand this would be of great help. Thank You

Comment: You can also configure custom session cookie name in `Startup / ConfigureServices()` method: `services.AddSession(options => { options.Cookie.Name = ".MyApp1.Session"; });`

Comment: My scenario was slightly different.  I had two asp.net core applications running.  Application A redirects to Application B, which redirects back to Application A.  The redirect back to Application A caused the "Error unprotecting the session cookie." error to get logged in the event viewer (users did not see any error).  Naming cookies in both apps as you suggest fixed the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, as I run the same app for prod and test on the same server (prod: port 443, test another port). I ended up to define a "shortname" for the app ("MG" in my case) , read the environment (prod/test) from .ini at startup and generate the cookie name dynamically at runtime (MGT for test, MGP for prod). This way I can run the same app without code change on the same server and also run other app's later (with other shortnames) on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `.AddAuthentication` defined in `Startup / ConfigureServices()`, to fix this add cookie options this way. Worked for my case.

```
  services.AddAuthentication(CookieScheme) // Sets the default scheme to cookies
             .AddCookie(CookieScheme, options =>
             {
                 options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
                 options.LoginPath = "/login";
                 options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder()
                 {
                     IsEssential = true,
                     SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                     SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
                     Name = ".AspNetCore.Session.yourAppName"
                 };
             });
```